# Warum wird "Sieg Heil" mit "hail victory" ins Englische übersetzt?

Tags: translation

Da "Heil" eine ganz andere Bedeutung als das englische "hail" (jubeln) hat, warum wird dieser Ausspruch allgemein so übersetzt?
Ist es nicht einfach falsch?

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sieg_Heil

Comment: "to heil" ist ein "richtiges" englisches Verb, siehe Wiktionary. Deine Überschrift ist wahrscheinlich einfach nur falsch geschrieben.

Comment: Isn't this a question about English rather than about German?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Auf der [von dir als Quelle angegebenen Seite](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sieg_Heil) steht das:

> From German *Sieg (“victory”) + Heil (“hail”)*, a common chant at political rallies in Nazi Germany, literally meaning "Hail Victory!". It should be noted however that the German "Heil" does not carry the same connotations of the English "hail". Whereas "hail" is most commonly used as a greeting or a salute, "Heil" translates more accurately as "salvation" or "good health". A more accurate translation therefore is "Victory brings salvation" or "Victory is salvation".

Übersetzung (Fette Hervorhebung von mir):

> Abgeleitet vom deutschen Sieg + Heil, einem in Nazi-Deutschland üblichen Ruf bei politischen Kundgebungen, der wörtlich "Hail Victory!" bedeutet. **Es ist jedoch anzumerken, dass das deutsche "Heil" nicht die gleiche Bedeutung wie das englische "hail" hat. Während "hail" meist als Gruß oder Salut verwendet wird, bedeutet "heil" eher "Rettung/Erlösung" oder "gute Gesundheit". Eine genauere Übersetzung ist daher "Der Sieg bringt Erlösung" oder "Der Sieg ist die Erlösung".**

Das Wort *»heil«* wird in Westen Österreichs (Tirol) auch heute noch als Gruß verwendet (*»Heil Sabine, wie geht's dir?«*) ohne dass dabei irgendwelche Nazi-Konnotationen mitschwingen. Vor 100 Jahren (und davor) war *»heil«* in fast ganz Österreich und weiten Teilen Bayerns ein üblicher Gruß, der erst durch die Nazis vergiftet wurde. Das Wort ist mit heilen, etwas ist heil (geblieben), heilig, Heil und Segen usw. verwandt und bedeutet Glück und Gesundheit (eigentlich "Ganzheit" wie in *»Die Tasse fiel auf den Boden, blieb aber heil.«*; auch das englische Wort *whole* ist damit verwandt). Mit dem Gruß *heil* wünscht man also jemanden Glück und Gesundheit.

Das englische Wort *hail* entstammt ebenfalls derselben etymologischen Wurzel (Glück und Gesundheit) und wurde eine Zeit lang (ungefähr im 16. und 17. Jahrhundert) ebenfalls als Gruß mit derselben Bedeutung wie das deutsche *heil* verwendet. Daraus hat sich dann unter anderem die Phrase *»Hail to the Chief«* entwickelt, die in den USA vertont und zur offiziellen Begrüßungshymne wurde, die immer dann gespielt wird, wenn der Präsident der Vereinigten Staaten bei offiziellen Anlässen erscheint. Allerdings hat sich im englischen Sprachraum dieser spezielle Gruß dann zu einem gemeinschaftlichen Zujubeln gewandelt, weswegen *to hail* heute eher mit Zujubeln assoziiert ist.

Allerdings wurden von den Nazis die Grüße *»Heil Hitler«* und *»Sieg Heil«* auch häufig vom jubelndem Volk ausgerufen um ihrem Führer zu huldigen. Daher gibt es gerade in *»Sieg Heil«* durchaus eine starke Komponente, die mit dem englischen *»hail«* verwandt ist, vor allem auch, weil *»heil«* in *»Sieg Heil«* wohl kaum noch als Wunsch nach Glück und Gesundheit interpretiert werden kann.